# What is the syntax to specifing multiple gem constraints in a Rails Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, gemfile

What is the correct syntax for the Gemfile for multiple dependencies?

When trying to use Capistrano, I'm getting an error message:

```
cap aborted!
NotImplementedError: unsupported key type `ssh-ed25519'
net-ssh requires the following gems for ed25519 support:
 * rbnacl (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
 * rbnacl-libsodium, if your system doesn't have libsodium installed.
 * bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
See https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/478 for more information
Gem::LoadError : "can't activate rbnacl (< 5.0, >= 3.2.0), already activated rbnacl-5.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile."
```

I put the following into my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rbnacl', '>= 3.2, < 5.0', :require => false
gem 'rbnacl-libsodium', :require => false
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '>= 1.0, < 2.0', :require => false
```

The gems (and req false) were previously in the Gemfile.

When I added the version requirements, bundle install gives the following error:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Illformed requirement [">= 3.2, < 5.0"]. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/myname/MySite/Gemfile:70
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    gem 'capistrano-maintenance', '~> 1.0', :require => false
 >    gem 'rbnacl', '>= 3.2, < 5.0', :require => false
 #    gem 'rbnacl-libsodium', :require => false
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrays or just list it out:

```
gem 'rbnacl', ['>= 3.2', '< 5.0']
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '>= 1.0', '< 2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install 'rbnacl:<5.0' rbnacl-libsodium 'bcrypt_pbkdf:<2.0'
```